# Angular 2 Injectable Class not working when creating and initializing parameters

Tags: typescript, angular

I wanted to create a Class to share some common api data accross a sample app but I can't understand why one of the two below versions are not working:

**Version 1 [./apiKeys.ts] - working**

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
@Injectable()
export class SomeApi{
  key: string;
  url: string;
  constructor(){
    this.key = 'API_KEY';
    this.url = 'API_URL';
  }
}
```

**Version 2 [./apiKeys.ts] - not working**

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
@Injectable()
export class SomeApi{
  constructor(
    public key:string = 'API_KEY',
    public url:string = 'API_URL'
  ){}
}
```

I will then pass it as a provider at bootstrap

**./main.ts**

```
import {SomeApi} from './apiKeys.ts'
bootstrap(AppComponent, [SomeApi])
```

But at startup I am getting the following error (considering *version 2*):

```
ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: No provider for String! (SomeApi -> String)
```

**Why is version 2 not working?**
Thanks

---

### EDIT

After the suggestions from Günter Zöchbauer I had a look at some resources and found what I think is the best solution for my situation, here is what I did:

**./apiKeys.ts**

```
import { OpaqueToken } from '@angular/core';

export interface AppConfig{
  key: string;
  url: string;
}

export const DI_CONFIG: AppConfig = {
  key: 'AIzaSyAjC3U-CbKYm_4sYV90XqJ_Upe8ID9jlxk',
  url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search'
}

export let APP_CONFIG = new OpaqueToken('app.config');
```

**./main.ts**

```
import { bootstrap }    from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import {DI_CONFIG, APP_CONFIG} from './apiKeys';

bootstrap(AppComponent, [{ provide: APP_CONFIG, useValue: DI_CONFIG }]);
```

**./apiService.ts**

```
import {Injectable, Inject} from '@angular/core';
import {APP_CONFIG, AppConfig} from './apiKeys';

@Injectable()
export class ApiService{
  constructor(
    @Inject(APP_CONFIG) private config: AppConfig
  ){}
  // i can then use it with this.config.url - this.config.key
}
```

*Sources:*

- https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html#!#non-class-dependencies
- http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/09/17/resolve-service-dependencies-in-angular-2.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't add `@Inject(...)` to constructor parameters, Angulars DI uses the parameter type as key to look up providers.

In your case this is `string` for both parameters which is ambiguous.
You also didn't register providers at all.

You need to provide with an artificial key like

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [
  {provide: 'myKey', useValue: 'A'}, 
  {provide: 'myUrl', useValue: 'B'}, 
  SomeApi
])
```

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
@Injectable()
export class SomeApi{
  key: string;
  url: string;
  constructor(){
    @Inject('myKey') this.key = 'API_KEY';
    @Inject('myUrl') this.url = 'API_URL';
  }
}
```

If you don't want to provide these values, you can use `@Optional()` like

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
@Injectable()
export class SomeApi{
  @Optional() key: string;
  @Optional() url: string;
  constructor(){
    this.key = 'API_KEY';
    this.url = 'API_URL';
  }
}
```

then DI only injects if it finds a matching provider.

Comment: Thanks for your precious help. I have edited my question since I have added what I think could be another approach since those dependencies I wanted to inject were just strings and using a class with string parameters was just a "workaround".